# K-Means Clustering From Scratch in Python

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

I've been trying to implement a simple k-means clustering algorithm from scratch in python/numpy. Initially I used a random array of size [1000,2] as a "dataset," so I could plot it easily, and my code seems to be working (dividing the points into k sections, placing centroids at the center of each section). Now I'd like to test it on a dataset with actual groups, so I concatenated two smaller arrays. It works as intended when k=2. However, larger values of k don't work; the number of points in each cluster seems to be 0 for some reason, and it returns a mean of empty slice warning, invalid value encountered in true_division on line 42 (dividing by 0 in np.mean() gives NaN). I tried seeing where the centroids are that it doesn't assign any points to some clusters, and plotting them only shows 1 centroid (instead of k centroids) at (0.5,0.5). Why do the other centroids not show, and why do some centroids not have their clusters?

I've tried initializing the centroids at random points in the dataset (instead of initializing them entirely at random) and it still often (it has worked a couple times) results in the same error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w1 = np.random.uniform(0.8,1.0,(50,2))
w2 = np.random.uniform(0.0,0.2,(50,2))
X = np.concatenate((w1,w2),axis=0)

def dist(a,b):
    a = np.reshape(a,(1,np.shape(a)[0],np.shape(a)[1]))
    b = np.reshape(b,(np.shape(b)[0],1,np.shape(b)[1]))

    dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(a-b), axis=2))

    a = np.reshape(a,(np.shape(a)[1],np.shape(a)[2]))
    b = np.reshape(b,(np.shape(b)[0],np.shape(b)[2]))
    return dist

def k_means(k, X):
    centroids = np.random.rand(k,np.shape(X)[1])

    error = 1
    while error != 0:
        prevcen = centroids

        cluster = np.argmin(dist(X,centroids), axis=0)

        clusters = {}
        points = {}

        for i in range(k):
            point = np.empty((0,np.shape(X)[1]))
            for j in range(np.shape(X)[0]):
                if cluster[j] == i:
                    concatenation = np.reshape(X[j,:],(1,np.shape(X)[1]))
                    point = np.concatenate((point, concatenation), axis=0)
            points = {i: point}
            clusters.update(points)

        for i in range(k):
            points = clusters[i]
            centroids[i,:] = np.mean(points, axis=0)

        error = np.linalg.norm((prevcen - centroids))

    return clusters, centroids

    k = 4
    clusters, centroids = k_means(k,X)

    colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "beige", "yellow", "magenta","purple", "pink", "cyan", "gray"]

    plt.scatter(centroids[:,0], centroids[:,1], s=20, c="black")

    for i in range(k):
        cluster = clusters[i]
        plt.scatter(cluster[:,0], cluster[:,1], s=5, c=colors[i])

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  This code won't run as displayed.

Comment: You should first take the operations out of functions and run line by line to find out where exactly it is failing. At first sight I saw that your points = {i: point} gives a 2-dim array for some i, and just empty array for some other i. Naturally centroids[i,:] = np.mean(points, axis=0) calculation produces the error you mention in your question. Now your cluster are unstable. Sometimes it gives you only two clusters, sometimes 3 etc. It is supposed to always give you 4 clusters. Therefore I suspect your dist function is wrong. Explain what exactly it is doing and I'll give you an answer.

Comment: Please explain this also: In your dist function you calculate dist = np.sqrt(...) Why do you still reshape a and b after that calculation? What is the point of that? I think the confusion has to do with that.

Comment: The dist function is used to calculate euclidean distance between each row of each of the arrays (to compare the distance between each point and each centroid); it should be equivalent to np.linalg.norm((a-b),axis=1). I reshaped both arrays to 3 dimensions to take advantage of broadcasting, so as to not have to run a for loop through each row. I reshaped it back to the original dimensions to make future indexing and operations more intuitive. Thanks a ton for looking at this @FatihAkici!

Comment: @LunarLlama Say X is 10 by 2. 10 observations on Cartesian plane. Dist should return 10 by 4, i.e., distance of each point to the 4 centroids. In that case correct expression must have a transpose at the end, and is np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(a-b), axis=2)).T Does that make sense?

Comment: @FatihAkici I had dist with axis=2 already in the code, so I think it should be matching up with np.linalg.norm((a-b),axis=1), aside from the transpose. The strange thing is the program works perfectly for a randomly initialized dataset X, without the concatenated arrays. Thanks again for taking the time for looking at this!

Comment: You should think about what value you want the centroid to take when no points are assigned to it (which can happen quite easily as you've set up the algorithm!)

Comment: @jakevdp How do I ensure each centroid has points assigned to it? I tried initializing the centroids at points in the dataset (instead of at random), but some centroids still are apparently not being assigned clusters occasionally (it has worked a couple times). I also noticed that if I plot the centroids as they are at initialization, it only shows 2 points, even though there should be k centroids; I can't figure out why. Thanks for the help!